# key mapping <C-'> (Ctrl single quote) not working

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, normal-mode

I have this line in my `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <C-'> :marks<CR>
```

and want to use <kbd>Ctrl-'</kbd> to show all marks.

Sadly, it never works, be it on ubuntu, cygwin, or windows 10.

After vim 8.0 was launched, type `:nn <C-'>` echos

```
n  <C-'>       * :marks<CR>
```

Thus I wonder, is it possible to reliably remapping `<C-'>`? or I missed something?

Comment: You can't map `<C-'>` it just results in a `'` in vim. have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101253/vim-mapping-ctrl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. (For `<C-'>`, I get a `'` in GVIM.) This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim release.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a mac, download https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org

This will let you turn *any* ctrl-key combination into a real character which you can then map. Use the "Complex modification" feature to do so. You can download modifications that others have submitted to a central repo or you can roll your own with a simple-to-use json file. See documentation for guidance.

I'm sure similar programs exist on windows and linux. Anyone?